# Second div to autoplayed always 1 sec after the first div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is how can I have `#slider` to be played always 1 second after `#faded`. Having it in 4 secs and 5 secs is not a stable way.

```
$(function(){
    $("#faded").faded({
        autoplay: 4000
    });
});

$(function(){
    $("#slider").faded({
        autoplay: 5000
    });
});
```

Comment: when you ask question about a plugin its nice to mention the name of plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want / need? It will fade in the first element after 4 seconds and when that is done, it will trigger a second timer after 1 second:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#faded').fadeIn('normal', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#slider').fadeIn('normal');
        }, 1000);
    });
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one problem you are facing:

`$(function(){...` this event happens before the page is render, thus creating inconsistencies in your code.

I would recommend that you change it to  `window.onload = function (){....`

this should fix the problem.